# sonata_type_date_picker somehow makes -1 day after saving entity

Tags: symfony, date, jquery-ui-datepicker, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Did someone experience this? I have date in datepicker.

https://monosnap.com/file/MfiUeANHvBjQjypTfW3jZqBbxKKCRU

After saving: https://monosnap.com/file/9nLR0yRYfccCVoGcRHkR1KST1zIUMJ

And everytime like this!

edit: Guys, somehow problem was related to php version. I had 7.0, now 7.1

The thing is... Default format for datepicker changed in php7.1 version and it was incorrect, so I changed option 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy' and **now everything is fine**, but! What does php version to do with this thing? How can it change default datepicker format? Can somebody explain this? Did anyone experience this type of problem?

Comment: At a guess your problem is likely timezone related. I don't have access to your version of sonata admin (mine is much older) so I can only offer a guess. Assuming it probably extends symfony datetime type in some way I would look into model_timezone and view_timezone options. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html

Comment: Thaks for comment! It seems that the problem is with jquery plugin on config for it. Tried changing view_timezone and model_timezone - nothing. Problem is still there. From request I'm getting everytime -1 day date.

Comment: edit: In form I'm getting everytime -1 day date. But in request I have valid chosen date. https://monosnap.com/file/6BPuV74GmxwvVRnYwUBMfxwRODRhuZ

Comment: What's your local timezone, and what's the timezone your database uses? Are you seeing any problems with any other date fields?

Comment: @Richard, when I'm not using datepicker sonata gives me 3 inputs for day, month and year. Everything is fine when I use those inputs.

The problem is somewhere betwee applying date data from post request into form data. Some datatransformer for datepicker changes date to -1 day. I'm not pro in insides of Sonata so I cannot tell really much about how my date from datepicker being changed, so looking for solution. Any other date is working fine. Local timezone is correct - Europe/Moscow